# Why CSS ease is not working on mouse out?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a problem with transition, and I do not know why?

Ease does work on mouse in, but on mouse out it just jumps back and there is no ease out, nothing happens...

Here is my CSS code:

```
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper {
  overflow:hidden !important;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper img:hover {
  overflow:hidden !important;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

Comment: The first selector is for the wrapper whereas the second is for the `img:hover`. Did you intend for it to be that way (or) is it a typo?

Comment: i want an img inside wrapper to zoom in and out, so i think its not a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a smooth transition to happen both during mouse-in and mouse-out on the image then both the states (the un-hovered and the hovered) should have the `transition` setting applied.

In the code shown in question, the `img` scales to 1.1 on hover-ing along with a transition but on hover out, there is no transition because the image (`img`) gets a transition setting for only as long as `hover` selector is applicable (which is, only when the mouse is inside the image).

In order to produce the effect that is seen in this [link](http://themeforest.net/item/love-travel-creative-travel-agency-wordpress/full_screen_preview/7704831), the following changes should also be done:

- Make the wrapper have the same height and width as the `img` (set it to `display:inline-block`)
- Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent. This would mean that the parts of the image which exceed the original dimensions of the wrapper will be cropped.

**Aside:** Remove `overflow: hidden` on `img`. This was actually never required because `img` cannot have children tag and so `overflow` doesn't really have any effect.

```css
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black; /* Just for demo */
}
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper img {
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /*transition: all 2s ease; no need to mention this as it is same setting as default */
}
```

```html
<div class='wpb_single_image'>
  <div class='vc_single_image-wrapper'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1' />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Part of Original Answer:** (not applicable now due to comment)

Or, you could apply both states on the wrapper (depending on your needs) like in the below snippet.

Applying the `:hover` on the wrapper will be equivalent to applying `:hover` on the `img` as long as the wrapper and `img` are same size and there is no space (like padding) between the wrapper and `img`.

```css
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  display: inline-block; /* this is required because wrapper is by default 100% width */
}
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /*transition: all 2s ease; no need to mention this as it is same setting as default */
}
```

```html
<div class='wpb_single_image'>
  <div class='vc_single_image-wrapper'>
    <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this right now, changed my code, but it does not do what i want. See this [link](http://themeforest.net/item/love-travel-creative-travel-agency-wordpress/full_screen_preview/7704831) hover over CUBA. I want zoom like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper img{
    overflow:hidden !important;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
 }

.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper img:hover {
    overflow:hidden !important;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;

 }
```

Update your code like the above.. It will work fine :)

Comment: I did that, than ease works fine. Problem is that it zooms whole wrapper, so it looks like img has changed its width and height. i need something like this [link](http://themeforest.net/item/love-travel-creative-travel-agency-wordpress/full_screen_preview/7704831) hover over Cuba or any other img.